# systemverilog module namespaces

Tags: module, namespaces, system-verilog

I am combining two designs into a single chip design.  The RTL code is written in SystemVerilog for synthesis. Unfortunately, the two designs contain a number of modules with identical names but slightly different logic.

Is there a namespace or library capability in SystemVerilog that would allow me to specify different modules with the same name?  In other words is there a lib1::module1, lib2::module1 syntax I could use to specify which module I want? How is this sort of module namespace pollution best handled?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look into `config` and `library`. See [IEEE Std 1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) § 33. *Configuring the contents of a design*

`library` will map this files to target libraries based on file paths ([IEEE Std 1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) § 33.3. *Libraries*)
`config` will map which library to use for paralytic module (global, instances, subscope) ([IEEE Std 1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) § 33.4. *Configurations*)

Examples are provided in the section 33.8.
Note: some simulators want `-libmap <configfile>` in the command line. Refer to your simulators manual.

Comment: @dave_59, I don't realize *-2017 became free do download for non-subscribers IEEE Xplore. A pleasant surprise

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, neither verilog nor system verilog provide a comprehensive solution for the namespaces problem for design element (which include modules). V2K libraries and config statements (yes,they were introduced in verilog v2k) can *partially* help you solving this issue for modules only, and only if you plan for this in advance and use correct methodology to implement it. Not many people try to use v2k libs to solve it.

There are other parts of this as well, which you might discover. It include other design elements, macro names, file names, package names, ... System verilog makes it even worse with introducing of the global scopes.

So, depending on the complexity of your design you might be able to fix it with v2k libs. But in general, the solution always lies in the methodology and having those names uniquified upfront. Some companies even try to use on-fly uniquification by automatically rewriting verilog code in order to make those names unique.

You might also be able to solve some of the issues like that using **compilation units**, as defined in the SV standard and which are implemented at least by major tool vendors.