# Compile + elaborate design with identical cell names

Tags: verilog

I am compiling a design which which uses cells defined in 2 lib files.

In both lib files there is a cell, in example below : `ff`, with identical name,
this causes the compiler to fail.

What I've tried:

1. edit lib_file1.v - change ff name to d_ff (Ugh! lib_file1.v is a third party we don't want to touch it)
2. include files without -v option. this works but then lots of redundant cells get compiled.
3. compile into different libraries - this does not work as fail is in elaboration phase

Is there a way to tell the compiler to use only the cell defined in the lib file where its instantiated, without editing the lib_files.

The file list looks like this:

```
top.v
-v lib_file1.v
-v lib_file2.v
```

file lib_file1.v

```
//other cells which use ff
module slow_ff(....);
    ............
    ff i_ff(D, Q, CP);
endmodule

module ff(D, Q, CP);
.....
endmodule
```

file lib_file2.v

```
//other cells which use ff
module fast_ff(...);
    ..........
    ff i_ff(D, Q, CP, EN);
endmodule

module ff(D, Q, CP, EN)
.....
endmodule
```

EDIT : top.v does not directly instantiate ff, it uses the "wrapper cells" (slow_dff and fast_dff in example). The issue is that if lib_file1.v was compiled first the linker will use ff defined in lib_file1.v also for lib_file_2.v

Comment: Are you using vcs?  there is no such thing as synopsys '-v' library in standard verilog. So, might need to get rid of -v and use standard v2k configurations. BTW,. it always compiles all the modules, no matter of -v.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer. Reffer [IEEE 1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) &sect; 33. _Configuring the contents of a design_. See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828979/systemverilog-module-namespaces/57829194#57829194)

Answer (score 0):

There are *configurations* in Verilog, but I'm thinking the easy solution to your problem might be this:

```
module top (...);
  ...
  `uselib file=lib_file1.v
  ff ff1 (...);
  `uselib file=lib_file2.v
  ff ff2 (...);
  ...
endmodule
```

Comment: @Mathew Taylor I edited the question to better explain the issue

Comment: there is no such directive in verilog standard.

Comment: @serge No, there isn't. It works in some simulators and not in others.